# jquery/javascript - hide div if containing image is broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a div with the class 'userFeatureProductImage'. this div is repeated however occasionally a broken image might come through so i want to hide the div as a precaution if this does happen. how can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The load event is only fired if an image is valid:

```
$('.userFeatureProductImage').hide();
$('.userFeatureProductImage img').load(function() {
  $(this).closest('.userFeatureProductImage').show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [error](http://api.jquery.com/error/) event which is called when an error occurs with the image:

```
$(".userFeatureProductImage img").error(function(){
   $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/vWwpc/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me... http://jsfiddle.net/UzEKZ/1/ ; The documentation makes it sound like it only hides the broken image icon for IE users.

Comment: hi this doesnt work for me either. just wondering would this just hide the image instead of the parent div?

Comment: hi got it to work, $(".userFeatureProductImage img").error(function () {
                $(this).parent().hide();
            });

Comment: Hi - not entirely certain why this is the case. I've added a working example, but for some reason it doesn't work correctly when I have it in the 'JavaScript' box. Possible because the event is raised before. I've also updated it to hide the parent div.

Comment: Ahh - it wasn't working in jsFiddle but when I changed the wrap to onDomReady, it worked.

Comment: The problem somehow is when to do this. The image has already to be recognized by the client, by this you have to do it at the end of the document or on ready-event, but if you do this, the error may already happen, the binding to error is to late. The suggestion by divby1 should be a better way.      `<img onerror="$(this).parents('.userFeatureProductImage').hide()" src="missing.jpg" />`

Answer (score 2):

You might try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function hideBrokenImage(id) {
          $(id.+"userFeatureProductImage").hide();
     }
</script>
<div id="imageFilename" class="userFeatureProductImage">
     <img src="imageFilename.gif" onerror="hideBrokenImage(imageFilename);" />
</div>
```

Where imageFilename is obviously dynamically created.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery equivalent of PHP's file_exists()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490237/jquery-equivalent-of-phps-file-exists)